# Linear models for robotic perception analysis

Tags: mixed-model, anova

**Background**

I am working on a project where I design perception algorithms for a robot. I have full control over the hardware design of the robot.

I want to analyze how different hardware choices affect the performance of the perception algorithm.

**Example**

Consider this example where I have the following explanatory variables and covariates:

- *Camera A* and *Camera B*
- *Robot motion path A* and *Robot Motion Path B*

My independent variable is *Image error*. The *Image error* occurs on multiple different levels:

- Per pixel
- Per image
- Per motion path

The example dataframe might look something like this

```
|Image Error|Image sequence|Robot Motion Path|Camera|
|-----------|--------------|-----------------|------|
|0.870      |1             |A                |A     |
|0.060      |1             |A                |B     |
|0.013      |2             |A                |A     |
|0.561      |2             |A                |B     |
|0.932      |3             |A                |A     |
|0.957      |3             |A                |B     |
|0.369      |1             |B                |A     |
|0.202      |1             |B                |B     |
|0.960      |2             |B                |A     |
|0.938      |2             |B                |B     |
|0.668      |3             |B                |A     |
|0.668      |3             |B                |B     |
```

I want to analyze whether there is a significant difference between *Camera* choice and/or *Robot Motion Path*.

**Research**

Initially I wanted to just do a simple ANOVA. Since the residuals in this case aren't independent, I expect I have to use a mixed linear model instead.

**Problem**

Am I right in assuming I need to use a mixed linear model here instead of a regular ANOVA? If not, why? And what approach do I need instead?

Comment: What is your dependant variable ?

Comment: A pixel level error metric e.g. RMSE between depth maps.